# rails carrierwave uploading in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

is there a possibility to do the uploading process with carrierwave to amazon S3 in background so that the action is done just by clinking the button and the upload is done in a separate process without blocking the website?

Thanks for hints and helping me.

Comment: You can use something like **Sidekiq** but then you should solve binding with assetable models.

Comment: have you a tutorial for me?

Comment: https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder - This could be of help.

Comment: @Sebin, set a good point for you